# How to supply session token as HTTP header using curl for authenticated web services php

Tags: php, api, curl

I am new to web development and PHP is not my favorite scripting language. Anyway, I am required to write a WordPress plugin to connect to a business API. I am able to authenticate the client. What I don't understand is how I can use the session token generated when the user is authenticated to request web services from the API. I am using curl.

```
function ExecuteRequest01($requestUrl,
                        $httpMethod,
                        $requestText,
                        $sessionToken,
                        &$responseText,
                        &$statusCode,
                        &$errorMessage,
                        &$responseContentType) {

    // Assume Success
    $Ok = TRUE;

    // Initialise ByRef
    $responseText = "";
    $statusCode = 0;
    $errorMessage = "";
    $responseContentType = "";
    $Header = array();

    // Initialise
    //$ContentType = "application/json";
    $ContentType = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8";

    // Create Header
    $Header[] = "Content-Type: " . $ContentType;
    $Header[] = "Accept: " . $ContentType;

    if (strlen($sessionToken) <> 0) {
        $Header[] = "Authorization: AuthFinWs token=\"" . $sessionToken . "\"";
    }

    // Initialise Request Handle
    $Request = curl_init();

    // Initialise URL
    curl_setopt($Request, CURLOPT_URL, $requestUrl);

    // Options
    curl_setopt($Request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    // Header
    curl_setopt($Request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $Header);

    // Timeout
    curl_setopt($Request, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 12); // 12 Seconds

    // HTTP Method
    curl_setopt($Request, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $httpMethod);

    // Write Request Body
    if (strlen($requestText) <> 0) {
        curl_setopt($Request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestText);
    }

    // Execute Request
    try {
        $responseText .= curl_exec($Request);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $Ok = FALSE;
        $errorMessage = $ex->getMessage();
    }

    // Retrieve Status Code
    $statusCode = curl_getinfo($Request, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    // Retrieve Content Type
    $responseContentType = curl_getinfo($Request, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);

    if ($statusCode != 200) {
        $Ok = FALSE;
    }

    // Close the Request Handle
    curl_close($Request);

    return $Ok;
}
```

When I try to access the web services it says: Authorization has been denied for this request.

Appreciate if someone points me in the right direction.

Comment: `$Header[] = "charset=UTF-8";` is **not** a valid HTTP request header value

Comment: What is a valid HTTP request header value? Please explain?

Comment: It should be obvious. Your other headers are all `Header-Name: value`. `charset=UTF-8` is not a valid header. Did you mean to append that to the `Content-type` header? If so, it should look like `Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8`

Comment: @Phil yes, I was trying to append that to `Content-type` header. Thank you for that.

Comment: Did that fix the issue?

Comment: No it did not. I have a separate php file which calls the `RequestUrl`: `Authentication\AuthenticateClient?` and another which calls `Client\GetAccounts?` The first one generates a `sessionToken`. How can I supply the `sessionToken` to the second `RequestUrl`?

Comment: That entirely depends on how it is meant to be sent. That would be dictated by the remote service

Comment: So the code I am using should be able to get the session token?

Comment: There are CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE and CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks..I'll try that